# Where is the Realtime Compositor in Blender 4.0 Beta?

Tags: compositing-nodes

It´s not in Experimental anymore. Is it gone?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to enable the preferences *Experimental* option anymore, it's now available in the *Viewport Shading*:

[image]

Comment: thank you very much!